# Writing to CSGO console using python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a script that automatically records specific rounds from specific matches in CSGO to record them during the night when I'm asleep.

To do this I have written a script that writes "playdemo cache_oct_2_2017" (where "cache_oct_2_2017" comes from a .csv-file that I made) in the console and presses enter. It gathers the right match from the file, puts the whole text into the console and presses enter just as it should. This tries to start a demo, but the game goes back to the main menu without going into the demo.

However, when I write the EXACT SAME TEXT in the console it does go into the demo. Is this an encoding thing? How do I work around it? I'm also printing the text in pycharms console, and the text is correct. When I copy the text from pycharms console into the csgo console it also doesn't work.

Code to start the demo looks like this:

```
def playNextDemo(demoFile):                 
    print('playdemo ' + demoFile)           
    command = 'playdemo '+ demoFile          
    execcommand(command)                    
    time.sleep(15)                          

def execcommand(command):                   
    keyboard.type(command)                  
    time.sleep(1)                           
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)               
    time.sleep(1)                           
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)             
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I'm interested in this! Have you found a way yet? Would you mind sharing if you did? :)

Answer (score 0):

In csgo you don't record with the command `'playdemo ' + demoFile`.
This command just starts the demo.

To record a demo you could do that:
[How to record a demo on CS:GO](https://steamcommunity.com/app/730/discussions/0/864973123395973905/) 
[How to record a POV demo](https://help.challengermode.com/en/articles/858184-how-to-record-a-pov-demo)

Comment: I know, this part is only to play the next demo. I then execcommand() to set time scale, go to the correct tick and then record using Shadowplay :)

Comment: The later parts work as they should (I have tried them inside a demo), but the launching of the demo doesn't :/

Comment: oh I see, my bad

Comment: It's fine, I should have been clearer hehe.. Anyway, do you have any idea why it won't work with the variable?

Comment: Something about it not being able to read the demo, but the text looks fine by eye, and when I write the same text manually it works as it should.. Does python do some magic when it adds/prints strings with variables?

Comment: you could try to first convert it into a string dave it in a variable and then print it or write it into a text file to see if python adds something.And then copy-paste what stands in the file into the console and see if it works.

Comment: Python doesn't add anything, I had spelled the demo name wrong :D

Still can't open the console after it's closed, but I will have to manage haha.. Thank you for the help!

Comment: No problem, even if I wasn't of much help.